# Disable macOS Finder confirmation: "Are you sure you want to add the extension to the end of the name?"

Tags: macos, finder, file-extensions

When I add a file extension to the end of a file name, macOS annoyingly nags me with a confirmation prompt:

[image: Are you sure you want to add the extension ".md" to the end of the name?]

> Are you sure you want to add the extension ".md" to the end of the name?
>
> If you make this change, your document may open in a different application.
>
> Don't add | Add

How can I disable this confirmation prompt?

Answer (score 3):

Finder > Preferences > Advanced

> Show warning before changing an extension

[image: Show warning before changing an extension]

Comment: Nice ......................